# check for previous record before applying function

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an array (or any other method of temporary storage) to test against to see if a certain record already exists; if it does I just want to add the record to the array - if it does not I have a function to create a node on a map, then I still want to add the record to the array.

The concept I have is to add a node to a map for each unit only once - the database will only contain unitnumb, lat, long, and time (which will be a datetime format) I have already queried the database and pulled up to the last 1000 records.

currently I have

```
            Dim mapcontains() As String = {""}


                For pop As Integer = 0 To filltab.Rows.Count - 1
                    current = filltab.Rows(pop)("unitnumb")
                    If Array.FindIndex(mapcontains, Function(s) s.Contains(current)) = 0 Then
                        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("AddMarker", New Object() {"Unit: " & filltab.Rows(pop)("unitnumb") & " at " & filltab.Rows(pop)("time"), filltab.Rows(pop)("lat"), filltab.Rows(pop)("long")})

                    End If
                    mapcontains(pop) = current
                Next
```

currently I tried adding each item to the array AFTER completing the if statement and comparing the array to see if it previously existed in the database and only running the addmarker script if it did not.

Currently this is not working, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be much, much better off using a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if you need separate data associated with the key) or a [Hashset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if you don't).

For example:

```
    Dim mapcontains As New System.Collections.Generic.HashSet(Of String)

    For pop As Integer = 0 To filltab.Rows.Count - 1
        current = filltab.Rows(pop)("unitnumb")
        If Not mapcontains.Contains(current) Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("AddMarker", New Object() {"Unit: " & filltab.Rows(pop)("unitnumb") & " at " & filltab.Rows(pop)("time"), filltab.Rows(pop)("lat"), filltab.Rows(pop)("long")})
            mapcontains.Add(current)
        End If
    Next
```